# self define auto-binning function with ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Tags: python

data is like:

```
+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
| SeriousDlqin2yrs | RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines | age | NumberOfTime30-59DaysPastDueNotWorse |  DebtRatio  | MonthlyIncome | NumberOfOpenCreditLinesAndLoans | NumberOfTimes90DaysLate | NumberRealEstateLoansOrLines | NumberOfTime60-89DaysPastDueNotWorse | NumberOfDependents |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                1 |                          0.186762647 |  44 |                                    0 | 0.579385737 |          1920 |                               5 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  4 |
|                1 |                          0.023579132 |  57 |                                    0 | 0.299046087 |          8700 |                              12 |                       0 |                            3 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.003621589 |  58 |                                    0 | 0.310172457 |          4000 |                              14 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  2 |
|                1 |                          0.145603022 |  77 |                                    0 | 0.313491151 |          4350 |                              10 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.245191827 |  53 |                                    0 | 0.238513897 |          7051 |                               3 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.443504996 |  23 |                                    0 |          54 |   6670.221237 |                               3 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |        0.757222268 |
|                1 |                          0.332611231 |  51 |                                    0 | 0.267748028 |          9000 |                               9 |                       0 |                            2 |                                    0 |                  6 |
|                1 |                          0.625243566 |  40 |                                    0 | 0.474557522 |          7231 |                               9 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  2 |
|                1 |                          0.091590841 |  51 |                                    0 |        2359 |   6670.221237 |                               3 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                           0.69186808 |  48 |                                    3 | 0.125587441 |         10000 |                               7 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  2 |
|                1 |                          0.004999828 |  63 |                                    1 | 0.246688328 |          4000 |                               5 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.064841612 |  53 |                                    0 | 0.239478872 |         11666 |                              13 |                       0 |                            3 |                                    0 |                  1 |
|                1 |                          0.512060051 |  44 |                                    1 | 0.412406271 |          4400 |                              14 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  1 |
|                1 |                            0.9999999 |  25 |                                    0 | 0.024314936 |          2590 |                               1 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.372130998 |  32 |                                    0 | 0.206849144 |          8000 |                               7 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  2 |
|                1 |                            0.9999999 |  34 |                                    0 | 0.208158368 |          5000 |                               4 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  2 |
|                1 |                          0.023464572 |  63 |                                    0 | 0.149350649 |          1539 |                              13 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.937531861 |  64 |                                    2 | 0.563646207 |         14776 |                               9 |                       0 |                            2 |                                    1 |                  1 |
|                1 |                          0.001808414 |  51 |                                    0 |        1736 |   6670.221237 |                               7 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.019950125 |  54 |                                    1 |        3622 |   6670.221237 |                               7 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.183178709 |  42 |                                    0 | 0.162644416 |          7789 |                              12 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  2 |
|                1 |                          0.039786673 |  76 |                                    0 | 0.011729323 |          3324 |                               6 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  1 |
|                1 |                          0.047418557 |  41 |                                    1 | 1.178100863 |          2200 |                               7 |                       0 |                            1 |                                    0 |                  2 |
|                1 |                          0.127890461 |  59 |                                    0 |          67 |   6670.221237 |                               2 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.074955088 |  57 |                                    0 |         776 |   6670.221237 |                               9 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                1 |                          0.025459356 |  63 |                                    0 | 0.326794591 |         18708 |                              30 |                       0 |                            3 |                                    0 |                  1 |
|                1 |                            0.9999999 |  29 |                                    0 |  0.06104034 |          3767 |                               1 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  3 |
|                1 |                          0.016754935 |  50 |                                    0 | 0.046870976 |          7765 |                               6 |                       0 |                            0 |                                    0 |                  0 |
|                0 |                          0.566751792 |  40 |                                    0 |   0.2010541 |          6450 |                               9 |                       1 |                            0 |                                    1 |                  4 |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+

# self define auto-binning function
def mono_bin(Y, X, n = 20):
    r = 0
    good=Y.sum()
    bad=Y.count()-good
    while np.abs(r) < 1:
        d1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": X, "Y": Y, "Bucket": pd.qcut(X, n)})
        d2 = d1.groupby('Bucket', as_index = True)
        r, p = stats.spearmanr(d2.mean().X, d2.mean().Y)
        n = n - 1
    d3 = pd.DataFrame(d2.X.min(), columns = ['min'])
    d3['min']=d2.min().X
    d3['max'] = d2.max().X
    d3['sum'] = d2.sum().Y
    d3['total'] = d2.count().Y
    d3['rate'] = d2.mean().Y
    d3['woe']=np.log((d3['rate']/(1-d3['rate']))/(good/bad))
    d4 = (d3.sort_index(by = 'min')).reset_index(drop=True)
    print("=" * 60)
    print(d4)
    return d4
```

have checked some answers,most of them suggested "to use something like iteritems."it seems differnet with mine

```
dfx1, ivx1,cutx1,woex1=mono_bin(data.SeriousDlqin2yrs,data.RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines,n=10)
```

> in ()
>   ----> 1 dfx1, ivx1,cutx1,woex1=mono_bin(data.SeriousDlqin2yrs,data.RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines,n=10)
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you chunk it and incrementally feed it into your structure?  Or, could you normalize the data such that points grouped up are weighted a little more?  (That would trim the dataset down)